# Find command returns different results when -print0 is added

Tags: find

When doing a search like `find -type d`, adding the -`print0` argument right after the find command such as `find -print0 -type d` causes the search to return more results than without it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you understand the `&&` and `||` operators in the shell
(and also in C, C++, and derivative languages),
then you understand `-a` and `-o` in `find`.

#### To refresh your memory:

In the shell,

```
command1  &&  command2
```

runs *`command1`*, and, if it (*`command1`*) succeeds,
it (the shell) runs *`command2`*.

```
command1  ||  command2
```

runs *`command1`*, and, if it (*`command1`*) fails,
it (the shell) runs *`command2`*.

In the compilable languages,

```
expr1  &&  expr2
```

evaluates *`expr1`*.  If it (*`expr1`*) evaluates to false (zero),
it returns that as the value of the overall expression. 
Otherwise (if *`expr1`* evaluates to a true (non-zero) value),
it evaluates *`expr2`* and returns that as the value of the overall expression.

```
expr1  ||  expr2
```

evaluates *`expr1`*.  If it (*`expr1`*) evaluates to a true (non-zero) value,
it returns that as the value of the overall expression. 
Otherwise (if *`expr1`* evaluates to false (zero))
it evaluates *`expr2`* and returns that as the value of the overall expression.

>   This is known as “short-circuit evaluation”,
>     in that it allows the evaluation of a Boolean expression
>     without evaluating terms whose values are not needed
>     to determine the overall value of the expression.

Quoting from [find(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find),

> GNU `find` searches the directory tree rooted at each given file name
> by evaluating the given expression from left to right,
> according to the rules of precedence (see section OPERATORS),
> until the outcome is known
> (the left hand side is false for **and** operations, true for **or**),
> at which point `find` moves on to the next file name.
>             ⋮
>
> ### EXPRESSIONS
>
> The expression is made up of … tests (which return a true or false value),
> and actions (which have side effects and return a true or false value),
> all separated by operators. 
> **-and** is assumed where the operator is omitted.
>                     ⋮
>
> >   *The subsection on **ACTIONS** states that **-print**, like
> >
> >   most of the actions, always returns a value of true.*
>
> ⋮
>
> #### OPERATORS
>
> ⋮
> *expr1* *expr2*
> *expr1* -a *expr2*
> *expr1* -and *expr2*    ⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅ **not POSIX compliant**
>
>   And;
>   *expr2*
>   is not evaluated if
>   *expr1*
>   is false.
>
> *expr1* -o *expr2*
> *expr1* -or *expr2*    ⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅ **not POSIX compliant**
>
>   Or;
>   *expr2*
>   is not evaluated if
>   *expr1*
>   is true.

The [Open Group Specification for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) has similar things to say:

> The *find* utility shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy …,
> evaluating a Boolean expression composed of the primaries
> described in the OPERANDS section for each file encountered.
>             ⋮
>
> #### OPERANDS
>
> ⋮
> **-print**
>
>   The primary shall always evaluate as true;
>   it shall cause the current pathname to be written to standard output.
>
> ⋮
> The primaries can be combined using the following operators
> (in order of decreasing precedence):
>             ⋮
> *expression* **[-a]** *expression*
>
>   Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied
>   by the juxtaposition of two primaries
>   or made explicit by the optional
>   **-a**
>   operator. 
>   The second expression shall not be evaluated
>   if the first expression is false.
>
> *expression*  **-o**  *expression*
>
>   Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. 
>   The second expression shall not be evaluated
>   if the first expression is true.

Both documents say,
“If no *expression* is present, **-print** shall be used as the expression.”

## ---------------- TL;DR ----------------

So,

```
find -type d
```

is equivalent to

```
find -type d -print
```

which is equivalent to

```
find -type d -a -print
```

which means,

- for each file,

  - evaluate the `-type d` test.
  - If it is true (i.e., if the current “file” is a directory),
    evaluate (perform) the `-print` action.

**Whereas**,

```
find -print -type d
```

is equivalent to

```
find -print -a -type d
```

which means,

- for each file,

  - evaluate (perform) the `-print` action
    *(i.e., this happens **for all files**)*.
  - If it is true (which `-print` always is), evaluate the `-type d` test.
  - And, since that’s the end of the command,
    the result of the `-type d` test is ignored.

So there you have it.

Comment: Nice explanation.  I'd suggest putting the TL;DR part first, but you have my vote either way.

Answer (score 10):

The order of find arguments matters.  The command needs to be constructed as `find -type d -print0` and then it will work as expected.  I just thought I'd post this in case it's helpful to anyone.

Comment: As to why order matters, [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) might be of interest

Comment: @1_CR; I skimmed through the linked document but couldn't exactly find the explanation why `find -print -type d` will return **all** files, given that the default logical connector is `-a` (AND), and `type -d` should thus also be considered. - My suspicion is that `-print` (always TRUE) will be effective before the whole logical expression is completely evaluated (which I feel to be counter-intuitive to the concept of logical expressions).

Answer (score 3):

The trick to understand a `find` command is to recursively evaluate and group into the resulting logic value's appropriate expression (`-true` or `-false`) the first two expressions / actions, considering that the evaluation of each pair of expressions / actions is short-circuited (hence expressions / actions as the second operand of an `AND` comparison will not be evaluated / evaluated and executed if the first evaluated expression is `FALSE` and expressions / actions as the second operand of an `OR` comparison will not be evaluated / evaluated and executed if the first evaluated expression is `TRUE`) and that **every action encountered during the process will be always evaluated as `TRUE` and executed at the time of its evaluation (if not skipped by a short-circuit evaluation) based on the logic value of the previously evaluated (and at the time of the evaluation already reduced to a `-true` or `-false` expression) pair of expressions / actions**.

Expanding an example in the useful [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) posted by 1_CR:

```
find . -false -o -false -a -printf 'nope\n' -o -printf 'yep\n' -o -printf 'nope\n'
yep
```

- `-false -o -false`: the first operand is an expression, so no action is executed, and its value is `FALSE`; the evaluation is not short-circuited, since `<expr1>` is `FALSE`, so `-false` is evaluated, and its value is `FALSE`; the whole expression's value is `FALSE`, and this is reduced to a `-false` expression which will be evaluated with the following expression / action;
- `-false -a -printf 'nope\n'`: the first operand is an expression, so no action is executed, and its value is `FALSE`; the evaluation is short-circuited, since `<expr1>` is `FALSE`, so `<expr2>` is not evaluated and not executed; the whole expression's value is `FALSE`, and this is reduced to a `-false` expression which will be evaluated with the following expression / action;
- `-false -o -printf 'yep\n'`: the first operand is an expression, so no action is executed, and its value is `FALSE`; the evaluation is not short-circuited, since `<expr1>` is `FALSE`, so **`printf 'yep\n'` is evaluated and executed now**, and its value is `TRUE`; the whole expression's value is `TRUE`, and this is reduced to a `-true` expression which will be evaluated with the following expression / action;
- `-true -o -printf 'nope\n'`: the first operand is an expression, so no action is executed, and its value is `TRUE`; the evaluation is short-circuited, since `<expr1>` is `TRUE`, so `<expr2>` is not evaluated and not executed; the whole expression's value is `TRUE`;

Doing the same on `find [...] -print0 -type d`, which expands to `find [...] -print0 -a -type d` (since a missing operator expands to an `AND` operator):

- `-print0 -a -type d`: the first operand is an action, so **`-print0` is evaluated and executed now**, and its value is `TRUE`; the evaluation is not short-circuited, since `<expr1>` is `TRUE`, so `-type d` is evaluated, and its value is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`; the whole expression's value is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on the `-type d` test's result;